How to add solution and project .vcxproj files to cloned repo with multiple projects and no Visual Studio (Community Edition) files
I created a repository using Visual Studio and Git and made a remote repository for it. The way it's structured is the repository (the root), three directories that are for a project each within the entire repository, meaning that each of those projects have their own source files respectively. One caveat is that I only added the directories and the source code, meaning that there's no Visual Studio solutions and project files in the remote repository:
hierarchy_repo/
├── First_Project/
│   └── main1.cpp
├── Second_Project/
│   └── main2.cpp
└── Third_Project/
    └── main3.cpp

How can I clone this so that I'm able to set up the solution and project (.vcxproj) and work with Visual Studio (Community Edition)?
Things to note is that Visual Studio will create a subfolder for solutions and projects .vcxproj
I want to replicate this structure as it was from the workspace in Visual Studio from my previous computer where the repo was pushed from:
hierarchy_repo/
├── .git/
├── First_Project/
│   ├── First_Project.vcxproj
│   └── main1.cpp
├── Second_Project/
│   ├── Second_Project.vcxproj
│   └── main2.cpp
├── Third_Project/
│   ├── Third_Project.vcxproj
│   └── main3.cpp
└── hierarchy_repo.sln

I tried cloning the repository through Visual Studio's cloning feature, then creating a solution by clicking "File" > "New" > "Project" > "Empty Project" and setting the path inside the cloned repo but things get messy because Visual Studio tends to create a subfolder for solutions and project files. Within this approach, I've also tried to move the solution manually through File Explorer but it doesn't update the paths of projects.
One thing I haven't got to explore is manually changing the solution file using a text editor like Notepad++ but where would that get me if Visual Studio will keep creating subfolders for new project files?
